# Rails ajax call not rendering my format.js file correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to mimic this http://samuelmullen.com/2011/02/dynamic-dropdowns-with-rails-jquery-and-ajax/ to make dynamic dropdowns using ajax.

Everytime i change my first dropdown, it calls my ajax function and gets into the correct js.erb file as seen by the log entry below, but it doesn't log anything in the console.

Log entry:

```
"available slots = 20"


Started POST "/arrangements/timeslots_by_location" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-11 17:59:25 -0500
Processing by ArrangementsController#timeslots_by_location as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (2.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `timeslots` WHERE (location_id = '3' AND arrangement_id is null)
  Timeslot Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `timeslots`.* FROM `timeslots` WHERE (location_id = '3' AND arrangement_id is null) ORDER BY timeslot ASC
  Rendered arrangements/timeslots_by_location.js.erb (6.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 11.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
"available slots = 20"


Started POST "/arrangements/timeslots_by_location" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-11 17:59:25 -0500
Processing by ArrangementsController#timeslots_by_location as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `timeslots` WHERE (location_id = '3' AND arrangement_id is null)
  Timeslot Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `timeslots`.* FROM `timeslots` WHERE (location_id = '3' AND arrangement_id is null) ORDER BY timeslot ASC
  Rendered arrangements/timeslots_by_location.js.erb (9.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 16.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

/views/arrangements/timeslots_by_location.js.erb

```
console.log('testing');
$("#arrangement_timeslot_id").html('<option value="2">TEST</option>');
```

In firebug, if i expand the post call from the console, i click the response tab and i see my javascript code, but it's not actually logging to the console or adding my option to my dropdown.

/controllers/arrangements_controller.rb

```
# Gets the available timeslots based on the location selected
  def timeslots_by_location
    if params[:id].present?
        @available_timeslots = Timeslot.where('location_id = ? AND arrangement_id is null', params[:id]).order('timeslot ASC')
    else
        @available_timeslots = []
    end
    p "available slots = #{@available_timeslots.size}"

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
    end
  end
```

views/arrangements/_form.html.erb

```
<%= collection_select(:arrangement, :location_id, Location.all, :id, :name) %>
```

assets/javascripts/arrangements.js

```
// Setup ajax calls to hit the format.js respond_to in my controller
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
    }
});    

// function that gets called when the location dropdown changes
$.fn.subSelectWithAjax = function() {
  var that = this;

  this.change(function() {
      $.post('/arrangements/timeslots_by_location', {id: that.val()}, null, "script");
  });
}

// Call the subSelectWithAjax function when the location dropdown changes
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#arrangement_location_id").subSelectWithAjax();
});
```

What's up with this?

Comment: Can you show us the JS that makes the POST call to timeslots_by_location.js?

Comment: Updated with that info.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I hadn't posted my entire timeslots_by_locations.js.erb file.

This snippet was in there:

```
console.log('test = <%= options_for_select(@available_timeslots.map {|sc| [sc.timeslot, sc.id]}).gsub(/n/, '').html_safe %>');
```

and the `.gsub(/n/, '')` should have been `.gsub(/\n/, '')` so it was causing the `<option ..` tags to be `<optio ..`.